# SSIS 2005: Valid Month Abbreviations

Tags: excel, vb.net, windows, date, ssis

I am importing text/string dates from XL and manipulating in a vb script component.

Is the list of valid month abbreviations a Windows thing, an XL thing, a VB thing, an SSIS thing?  Is there any way to modify this list...specifically, add **Sept** as a valid abbreviation for **September**?

Some people like to use **Sept** (instead of **Sep**) for **September**, but **Sept** throws an error when converting to a date.

I would love to be able to set up my system so that both **Sep 2007** and **Sept 2007** will convert to **2007-09-01** seamlessly without any errors anytime I need to convert to a date data type.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide,

CTB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any source of alternate month abbreviations but for at least the sample provided of Sept vs Sep, the beautiful thing is that you only need the first 3 characters to match to be successful so in your script, use a substring/left function call to only pull back the first three characters of the month field.

C# approximately

```
if (!row.Column1_IsNull)
{
    // Split on white spaces
    var pieces = Column1.Split();

    // Variable for our date
    DateTime cleanDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    // Depending on how dirty the data, you might need a harder scrubber
    // Assumes the first element is a month name of varying brevity
    // the second element is the year
    // You might also need to patch in the 1 for the day of the month
    string clean = string.Format("{} {}", pieces[0].Left(3), pieces[1]);

    if (DateTime.TryParse(clean, cleanDate))
    {
        row.CleanDate = cleanDate;
    }
    else
    {
        // Error handling logic
        row.CleanDate_IsNull = true;
    }

}
```